# How can I convert a JPEG image to a PNG one with transparent background?

Tags: c#, image, png, jpeg

I have a JPEG format image, with a white background and a black circle.

How can I transform this image to a PNG format that the white background will be transparent and the black remains there?

I'm a programmer too, and if there are some ideas in C# code I will be very happy. Also I'm looking for a converter, tool, program anything.

Thank you.

Jeff

Comment: Any reasonable image editor (e.g. Paint.NET) would be able to do this.  Do you actually need code?

Comment: I don't actually need code, I want just the background to be transparent, it doesn't matter how and with what tool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is working, but slow solution. You can speed it up by using Bitmap.LockBits().

```
using (Image img = Image.FromFile(filename))
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img))
{
    for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
        {
            Color c = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
            if (c.R == 255 && c.G == 255 && c.B == 255)
                bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0));
        }
    }
    bmp.Save("out.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Comment: hmm, what should I import to use 'Image', 'Bitmap' and 'Color'?

Comment: You will need to reference System.Drawing.dll

Comment: ok, the code it's working fine.... my next question is: how do I know that my image has a really transparent background?

Comment: This is definitely not a programmers approach, but I would use color pick tool in Paint.NET to check :)

Comment: If this solution is too slow, it may be because `GetPixel` adds an extra layer of indirection.  Using `unsafe` code via pointers is likely faster, if necessary.  See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/csharpgraphicfilters11.aspx for examples, though you'll need to adapt them for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) tool [like this example](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=8359).

You will need to set the `-background` option to `transparent`, set the the `-alpha` option to `set` and use the `-transparent` option to set the colour you want to be interpretted as transparent.  See also the [convert tool reference](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php).