# Converting JPEG/PNGs to PNG for database storage but can't keep background transparency/colour when displaying, in PHP

Tags: php, image

I've a script I use to convert JPEGs or PNGs to PNGs for database storage, I encode the file into base64 and store it in a database, I pull the file from the database or cache and when displaying it on a website I just pull the image data from the database or cache and do a base64 decode on it and display it using a standard `IMG` tag.

The issue I'm having is, no matter if the background is transparent or what colour I create as the image's background it always shows up as black when being displayed on the webpage.

I've tried numerous of the questions on the right side and none of the answers seems to work for me.

**Encode Function**

```
public function encode($image, $resize = false, $dirLevel = '')
{
    $vTempFileName = TEMP_DIR . '_'.rand(1111111, 9999999) . '.png';

    // Convert image to PNG
    $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image));
    imagealphablending($image, true);
    imagepng($image, $vTempFileName);

    $vImageDetails = array(base64_encode(file_get_contents($vTempFileName)), filesize($vTempFileName));

    // Remove temporary file after processing
    @unlink($vTempFileName);

    return $vImageDetails;
}
```

**Decode Function**

```
echo base64_decode($image);
```

I've also tried using the below two functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a JPEG image to a PNG one with transparent background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906260/how-can-i-convert-a-jpeg-image-to-a-png-one-with-transparent-background)

Comment: @HendraNucleo, thanks but that answer was for C#, my script is in PHP.

Comment: My mistake, retracted my flag :)

Answer (score 3):

To save transparency you need to add `imagesavealpha` See http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php

```
public function encode($image, $resize = false, $dirLevel = '')
{
    $vTempFileName = TEMP_DIR . '_'.rand(1111111, 9999999) . '.png';

    // Convert image to PNG
    $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image));
    imagealphablending($image, true);
    imagesavealpha($image, true);
    imagepng($image, $vTempFileName);

    $vImageDetails = array(base64_encode(file_get_contents($vTempFileName)), filesize($vTempFileName));

    // Remove temporary file after processing
    @unlink($vTempFileName);

    return $vImageDetails;
}
```

`imagefill` will perform a flood fill on the selected coordinates with the desired color defined as `$transparent` See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php

```
$fillColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127); 
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $fillColor);
```

To flood fill the adjoining color at the top left of the image with the desired fillColor.

Otherwise to add transparency use `imagecolortransparent` see http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php

```
$replaceBlack = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0); 
imagecolortransparent($image, $replaceBlack);
```

to replace the color black as transparent.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not help you but... you really don't want to store images into a database if you can avoid it. Is there a good reason you are doing this? File systems are good at storing binary files. Databases are good at storing data. Use the appropriate tool for the job – store it as a file.

Comment: You are correct in that fact that database storage is not optimal for images but I don't think the database is the issue in this case. I would imagine that `imagealphablending()` or `imagepng()` is the root of the issue.

Comment: For that matter, why is the OP converting JPEGs to PNGs, and why are they base64-encoding the images before storing them? (I've never heard of a database that didn't have a column type for binary data.) But yes, while this answer may not address the OP's *immediate* problem, I do believe that it's a valuable (I might even say essential) contribution to this page. +1 from me.

Comment: The images are stored due to the dynamic nature of the website and specific requirements for processing, security policy and backup plans. The images are essentially stored on the file server as the database is only queried once and then the image is cached on the web server, the database storage helps with the backup policy, so no data exists on the file server(s) apart from the cache that can be safely wiped if needed with no knock on affects. Appreciate the input though.